# Finding transformation in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation, conformal-geometry

I have to find the transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that goes from the 2D annulus to a square, and I am unsure if my procedure is right.

More precisely, the problem is as follows:

Find the transformation from the domain $A$ to $B$, where $A$ is described according to $(\xi, \eta) \in A = [-1,1]^2$ and $(r,\theta)\in B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ where $r \in [r_0, r_0 + \Delta r]$ and $\theta \in [-\frac{\Delta \theta}{2}, \frac{\Delta \theta}{2}]$

So I found from http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~olver/ln_/cml.pdf (page 29) that this is equivalent to the conformal mapping

$$(x, y) = (e^\xi\cos \eta, e^\xi \sin \eta)$$

But how do I constructively come up with this conclusion?

Comment: You are using the transformation $T(\bf{x})=M\bf{x}$. What makes you believe that your transformation will be *linear*? The edges of the annular region are not straight lines.

Comment: You're right. How can I find it if it is non-linear?